# Olive tree leaves are turning brown but stays on the branches

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, leaves, olive

We transplanted a mature olive tree way back March and it's been adjusting well on the new location. But starting mid of July, at the peak of summer here in Qatar, the leaves of 1 big branch started to turn yellow then brown. As of this day, most of the brown leaves stayed on the branches.

New leaves are starting to grow at the bottom of the tree. What is the best to do? It this caused by overwatering or suffering from verticillium wilt?

[image]